# Footnotes in LaTeX

Tags: footnotes

I'm trying to put two footnotes at the same location in my document, which is working, but the numbering for the footnotes doesn't correspond with the markers in the text.

The code I have is:

```
\begin{framed}
\noindent \textit{Sidenote:} The two results \footnotemark \footnotemark that Wiles needed to prove the theorem are given by the following equations: 
\begin{equation}
\rho_{f,p} \simeq \rho_{g,p}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
L(E,s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^s}
\end{equation} \newline \newline
\end{framed}

\footnotetext{Equation (1) is the equation corresponding to the $\varepsilon$ conjecture}
\footnotetext{Equation (2) is the equation corresponding to the modularity theorem}
```

and the result of this is that the markers at the word "results" are shown as 1,2 which is right, but the markers at the bottom of the page are both 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome! Please can you edit your question to provide compilable code?

Answer (score 3):

Please always provide compilable code, as this is much more useful than mere fragments.

Untested, but I think you want

```
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
\footnotetext{Equation (1) is the equation corresponding to the $\varepsilon$ conjecture}%
\stepcounter{footnote}%
\footnotetext{Equation (2) is the equation corresponding to the modularity theorem}%
```

But it would be better to use the `\label`-`\ref` system for the equation numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}


\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
  \noindent \textit{Sidenote:} The two results \footnotemark\footnotemark{} that Wiles needed to prove the theorem are given by the following equations: 
  \begin{equation}
    \rho_{f,p} \simeq \rho_{g,p}\label{eq:rho}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
    L(E,s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^s}\label{eq:sum}
  \end{equation} \newline \newline
\end{framed}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
\footnotetext{Equation (\ref{eq:rho}) is the equation corresponding to the $\varepsilon$ conjecture}%
\stepcounter{footnote}%
\footnotetext{Equation (\ref{eq:sum}) is the equation corresponding to the modularity theorem}%  
\end{document}
```

[image: footnotes and cross-referencing]

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, +1. Most likely the ultimately the OP won't use any footnotes here, they are just distracting. IMHO the information should go right under the equation.

Comment: @marmot Or they should be notes within a minipage or something. However, I think those should be used sparingly (as footnotes, also) and don't see any good case for them here.

Comment: I fully agree, and that's what I wanted to say.